# How to automatically hide files put in a specific folder?

Tags: windows

How should I go about automatically hiding files that I paste/drop in a folder, for example C:\test\ ?

I thought about creating a batch file or using a program which runs continuously on the desktop and scans for new files in the folder, then hides them.  However, I don't know what program, or what commands to put into the batch file.

Comment: Why don't you just hide the _folder_?

Comment: Because I add files daily, and it's a repetitive task to keep on going in the proterties/hide folders... I would like to automate it.

Comment: I mean hide the parent folder, that way you don't _need_ to hide the files and everything you add subsequently will be hidden because the folder itself is. This would be easier to understand if you explained why you want the files hidden, it sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @terdon exactly like i said in my answer

Comment: @terdon Files add inside a hidden folder are not hidde,n if you access the folder.

Comment: @Conrad I know, but if your objective is to have the files invisible it will work, that's what I mean by XY problem. Perhaps we will understand better if you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Conrad in terdon and my points if you were to browse to the root of your C: drive, you would see no /test folder. Therefore no one would know that there was a C:\test with the files you were hiding in it. If you want them to see some of the files in C:\test , then you could do the same thing with a C:\test\hidden folder. hide the folder named hidden and place your files to hide in that hidden folder. Now no one sees them unless they go looking for the folder.

Comment: Note that if you have show hidden files and folder turned on that you will still see the C:\test or C:\test\hidden folder, but regular people wouldnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I don't know what program, or what commands to put into the batch file.

I believe the command you are looking for is [`attrib`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx). Example:

```
attrib +h "c\dir\test1\*" /s
```

Where.

`+h`: Sets the hidden file attribute.

`/s`: Applies attrib and any command-line options to matching files in the current directory and all of its subdirectories.

---

See also this winapi [`SetFileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
SetFileAttributes(path, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
```

*You can use this function recursively to apply the appropriate attributes to the files in the folder.*

---

[Attribute Changer](http://www.petges.lu/home/)(Free).

[image]

> Attribute Changer is a freeware tool that allows you to set file
>   attributes on multiple files and folders, recursively.

Answer (score 2):

A different solution would be hiding the folder, files inside it are still visible, but you wont see the folder they are in listed (unless you have hidden files shown)

so, for example, if you Open C: you'll see WINDOWS, other crap and other other crap, but not C:\test

If you open C: then go to the bar and type in \test it will show you your hidden files very nicely

Comment: No, you're right, but you didn't seem to read my entire post. I didn't answer his question, I responded by confirming his suspicions and then offering an alternative to his thought process. Please actually READ my post and notice that I even said "A different solution would be hiding the folder" showing that I am not hiding the files, but instead the folder. Therefore making it an ALTERNATIVE. Let the OP be the judge of whose answer solves his problem.

Comment: I read your entire post, but the fact that you started off your answer by saying he needed "some kind of program" and essentially offering up for an answer exactly what he said already in his question was worth a downvote.  Terdon removed it, so I removed my downvote... however, oddly enough, now someone is serial downvoting my answers.  Funny that.

Comment: So you're saying that it's wrong that I confirmed what he thought before I offered an alternative? Why is that bad?

Comment: He says he wants to use a program of some kind to automatically check for new files and hide them.  You tell him as an answer that he needs "some kind of program" that will check for and hide the files automatically, **OR AS AN ALTERNATIVE** he can just hide the whole folder.  That's not confirming what he thought.  That's just repeating back to him what he said, and calling it an answer.  Shall I revert Terdon's edit so we can review your exact wording?

Comment: If you feel that terdons edit wasnt appropriate, then revert it. Would you have preferred I structure my answer differently and said "An alternative would be.... and if you want to hide the individual files you would need some program or something that I'm not aware of?" There are two parts to my answer, a conceptual approach to how a program such as he is looking for would work (not saying JUST that he needs one) AND offering an alternative that might be easier. There is always the possibility that he would have taken a shine to making his own program to check for new files and then hide 'em

Comment: Funny tho... Terdon removed what you said because you weren't just confirming his post, so I removed my downvote... and yet, I still have to live with the three downvotes I got in retaliation.  Fantastic.

Comment: I like to make my own tools, so i offered, conceptually, how i would approach writing a tool. Find new files (unhidden) and then hide them. I didn't fight that battle because this isnt stackoverflow and I thought he might not consider that as an option.

Comment: @BonGart also rather convenient that someone happened to come along and upvote you right after that. on two of those downvotes. thats a net gain of 24.

Comment: You said "To autohide the files you would need some kind of program that checks for new ones and hides them."  That's not taken out of context, that's the first freakin line in your previous answer.  http://imageshack.com/scaled/medium/9/749j.jpg There's a screen cap, so you can keep your edited post.  If I felt that Terdon's edit was inappropriate, I wouldn't have **removed my downvote**.  At this point, you are just attempting to change history, because what you said can't be seen anymore.

Comment: Someone came along and upvoted me, because I spoke up about the serial downvoting in chat.  Not because I removed my downvote.

Comment: I'm not hiding the fact that it was edited. http://superuser.com/posts/645358/revisions anyone can see this. And basically you got someone to serial upvote you. Literally anyone. Not even logged in.

Comment: @BonGart what down votes are you talking about? I certainly did not down vote you. You had _one_ "unupvote" today which hardly counts as "serial downvoting", and anyway, come one, you have >10k rep, you can deal with a measly -10 :).

Comment: @terndon I did not accuse you, or anyone by name.  I simply made the enormous mistake of actually providing a reason for my downvote.  Mysteriously, and immediately, I saw three downvotes appear on three different answers of mine.  It's not about the points.  It's about the retaliation for my having provided a downvote to this answer and standing up behind it.  Obviously I wasn't wrong about **what** I downvoted it for, since you went in and removed the same part of the post I commented on.  I notice how you can't say anything about that.  If there was nothing wrong with it, why'd you edit?

Comment: @BonGart - Its not the first time people have serial downvoted people for giving a reason they feel is wrong.  Your downvote on the question was reasonable.  I would have actually left it because it doesn't even provide a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a Scheduled Task every so often that performs the command:

```
ATTRIB +H "C:\Test\*" /S /D
```

This command sets all files and subfolders/files hidden within the target directory.

While this isn't *automatic* as you described you wanted, you could set it to run every few minutes.

You could also run the command as a batch after you place files in the folder, or assign it to a hotkey.

Comment: or all three for good measure :P

Comment: And on shutdown and startup XD

Comment: and anytime the computer is idle for more than a couple minutes (but less than how often you schedule it to run) XD

Comment: It could have a performance penalty if there are lots of files, especially if this command is run often.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov True, which is why an on-demand hotkey or shortcut would be the best option in that case.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt that there is a tool that does this. However, you could easily [create a Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) using C# or any other .Net language which observes this folder using the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). You could process files that are discovered in the [created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created.aspx) event and [set the attributes accordingly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx).

Comment: A comment about why this is downvoted would be nice. I don't know any tool that does what the OP wants. I saw that he's also on SO and posted multiple times under the .Net and C# tag. Why shouldn't this answer be a good answer leading him to a real solution for his specific problem?